# Cant update integer fields in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite

Okey i just dont understand what can be wrong here

i have this app where users are approved by and admin and this was working fine until a few days ago

in my view i have a link that calls my user controller

```
<%= link_to 'Approve', active_user_path(user), :method => :put %>
```

here is my custum route for that link

```
match "users/:id/activate" => "users#activate", :as => "active_user"
```

now in my user controller i have this activate method

```
def activate
  @user = User.find(params[:id])

  puts @user.name #the correct name is displayed
  puts @user.is_approved.inspect.to_i #:is_approved is 0

  if @user.update_attribute(:is_approved, 1) 

  puts @user.is_approved.inspect # :is_approved is 1

  @user.activate_user

  puts @user.is_approved.inspect # :is_approved is 1

  @user.save!

  redirect_to "/users?is_approved=0"

  else
   render "/" # dosn't matter
  end 
end
```

I try to save 3 times here (update, activate_user, save!) but still the value will not be saved, the users `is_approved` field is still 0, how is that possible ?

here is my model method

```
def activate_user
  self.is_approved = 1
  self.save
end
```

btw i can update strings with this method but not integers (true and false dosnt work either)

in my model i have `is_approved` as both attr_accessible and attr_accessor

**The solution**

Well this is awkward but so it happens that in my user model i had `attr_accessor :approved`  this resulted in that the model never went to the database to update the `:approved` column BUT instead it updated the local variable `:approved` so next time when i looked at the column then of course the `:approved` value had not changed

tldr? 
if you have attr_accessor in your model with the same name as the column your trying to update => remove it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never use `attr_accessor` on an attribute which is backed by a database column - the accessor generated by `attr_accessor` will mask the value stored in the database

Answer (score 1):

[update_attribute](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_attribute) actually does more than just updating a single column:

- Validation is skipped.
- Callbacks are invoked.
- updated_at/updated_on column is updated if that column is available.
- Updates all the attributes that are dirty in this object.

Are there any callbacks in your User model? 
Make sure the column is not being updated somewhere in a callback.

Comment: what kind of callbacks could there be? ive also tried to skip the update call and just set the `is_approved` to 1 and call save from the controller but still dosnt work

Comment: Could be after_save, but now I think Frederick's answer makes more sense than mine - it's more likely to be attr_accessor that spoils value changing.